# Import password filed as an functional component in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, import, functional-programming, components

***I want to store this react hook and password field in a separate js file and I want to import it to my register form how can I do that?***

**Password Field**

```
  <label class="font-medium block mb-1 mt-6 text-gray-700" for="password">
    Password
  </label>
  <div class="relative w-full">
    <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2">
      <input class="hidden js-password-toggle" id="toggle" type="checkbox" />
      <label class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 rounded px-2 py-1 text-sm text-gray-600 font-mono cursor-pointer js-password-label" for="toggle">show</label>
    </div>
    <input class="appearance-none border-2 rounded w-full py-3 px-3 leading-tight border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 focus:bg-white text-gray-700 pr-16 font-mono js-password" id="password" type="password" autocomplete="off"
    />
  </div>
```

**Password function filed**

```
useEffect(() => {

  const passwordToggle = document.querySelector('.js-password-toggle')

  passwordToggle.addEventListener('change', function() {
    const password = document.querySelector('.js-password'),
      passwordLabel = document.querySelector('.js-password-label')

    if (password.type === 'password') {
      password.type = 'text'
      passwordLabel.innerHTML = 'hide'
    } else {
      password.type = 'password'
      passwordLabel.innerHTML = 'show'
    }

    password.focus()
  })

}, [])
```

**Form That I want to add this password filed**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Buttons from "../../../elements/form/Button";
import PasswordInput from "../../../elements/form/PasswordInput";
import { Col, Input, Row, Select, Form, InputNumber, Divider } from "antd";
import { ChangePassword, sentOtp, changePhoneNumber, requestOtp } from "./SecurityApi";

const { Option } = Select;



const Security = () => {



  const [phoneNo, setPhoneNo] = useState("");
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState("");
  //const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [conPassword, setConPassword] = useState("");
  const [passError, setPassError] = useState();
  const [otpError, setOtpError] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);


  //changing password
    const [editPasswordState, setEditPasswordState] = useState(false);
    const [password, setPassword] = useState({
      password: "",
    });
    
    const handlePasswordChange = async () => {
      if (password === user.password) {
        return;
      }
      if (password.trim() === "") {
        console.log("cant be empty");
    
        return;
      }
    
      await ChangePassword(password, setUser);
    };

  useEffect(() => {
    setPassError(password && conPassword && password !== conPassword);
  }, [password, conPassword]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOtpError(!otp && phoneNo);
  }, [otp]);
//onSubmit password
  const onSubmit = async () => {
    if (passError) return false;
    try {
      const res = await ChangePassword({ password });
      setPassword("");
      setConPassword("");
      alert("Password Changed !!");
    } catch (error) {
      alert("Something went wrong !!");
    }
  };
//OTP
  const sendOtp = async () => {
    if (phoneNo === "") return false;
    try {
      const res = await sentOtp(phoneNo);
      alert(`Otp is ${res} !!`);
    } catch (error) {
      alert("Something went wrong !!");
    }
  };
//Changing the phone number
  const changePhoneNo = async () => {
    if (phoneNumber === "") return false;
    if (otp === "") {
      setOtpError(true);
      return false;
    }
    try {
      const res = await changePhoneNumber(phoneNo);
      setPhoneNumber("");
      setOtp("");
      alert("Phone Number Changed !!");
    } catch (error) {
      alert("Something went wrong !!");
    }
  };

  const [editPhoneNumberState, setEditPhoneNumberState] = useState(false);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState({
    password: "",
  });
  
  const handlePhoneNumberChange = async () => {
    if (phoneNumber === user.phoneNumber) {
      return;
    }
    if (password.trim() === "") {
      console.log("cant be empty");
  
      return;
    }
  
    await ChangePassword(password, setUser);
  };
   
  return (
    <>
      <div className="md:pl-8 sm:pl-0 ">
        {/*  ----------    Password Change  ------------  */}
        <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
          <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">
            <div class="md:col-span-1">
              <div class="px-4 sm:px-0">
                <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
                  Change Password
                </h3>
                <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600">Change password here</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
              <form action="#" method="POST">
                <div class="shadow overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
                  <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                  <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                    <Buttons
                      title={
                        !editPasswordState ? "Edit Full Password" : "Cancel"
                        }
                      outline
                      onClick={() => {
                        setEditPasswordState(!editPasswordState);
                      }}
                      class="inline-flex 
                            justify-center 
                            py-2 px-4 border 
                            border-transparent 
                            shadow-sm text-sm 
                            font-medium rounded-md 
                            text-white bg-red-400 
                            hover:bg-red-400 
                            focus:outline-none f
                            ocus:ring-2 
                            focus:ring-offset-2 
                            focus:ring-red-500"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                            {editPasswordState && (
                              <Buttons
                                title="Save"
                                onClick={async () => {
                                  setEditPasswordState(false);
                                  await handlePasswordChange();
                                }}
                              />
                            )}
                   </div>       
                   </div>  
                   </div>   
                  <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
{/* OTP Check*/}
<div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-1">
                      <div class="col-span-4 sm:col-span-3">
                        <label
                          for="first-name"
                          class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                        >
                          Send OTP
                        </label>

                        <Buttons
                          title={"Request OTP"}
                          outline
                          onClick={async () => {
                            await requestOtp(user.phoneNumber);
                            }}
                        />

                      </div>
                      <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                        <label
                          for="last-name"
                          class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                        >
                          Enter OTP
                        </label>

                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="last-name"
                          id="last-name"
                          autocomplete="family-name"
                          class="mt-1 
                                      focus:ring-red-400 
                                      focus:border-red-400 
                                      block w-full 
                                      shadow-sm sm:text-sm 
                                      border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                        />
                        {passError && (
                          <Col className="text-red-500">
                            OTP doesn't Correct !!
                          </Col>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </div>
{/* OTP Check End */}
                  </div>
                  <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
{/* Password Check*/}

                    <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                      <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                        <label
                          for="first-name"
                          class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                        >
                          New Password
                        </label>

                        <Input.Password
                          value={password}
                          onChange={(event) => {
                            setPassword(event.target.value);
                          }}
                          class="mt-1 
                          focus:ring-red-400 
                          focus:border-red-400 
                          block w-full 
                          shadow-sm sm:text-sm 
                          border-gray-300 rounded-md"/>
```

**This is the Place**

```
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                        <label
                          for="last-name"
                          class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                        >
                          Confirm New Password
                        </label>

                        <Input.Password
                          value={conPassword}
                          onChange={(event) => {
                            setConPassword(event.target.value);
                          }}
                        />
                        {passError && (
                          <Col className="text-red-500">
                            Password doesn't match !!
                          </Col>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </div>
{/* Password Check End*/}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/*    ------- End Password Change   --------   */}
        <div class="px-4 py-1 bg-black-50 text-right sm:px-6">
          <Divider></Divider>
        </div>
        {/*     ------------   Mobile Number Change  ----------------    */}

        <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
          <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">
            <div class="md:col-span-1">
              <div class="px-4 sm:px-0">
                <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
                  Change Mobile Number
                </h3>
                <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
                  Use a permanent address where you can receive mail.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
              <form action="#" method="POST">
                <div class="shadow overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
                  <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                  <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                      <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                    <Buttons
                      title={
                        !editPhoneNumberState ? "Edit Phone Number" : "Cancel"
                        }
                      outline
                      onClick={() => {
                        setEditPhoneNumberState(!editPhoneNumberState);
                      }}
                      className={" flex items-center justify-center "}
                    />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                          {editPhoneNumberState && (
                              <Buttons
                                title="Save"
                                onClick={async () => {
                                  setEditPhoneNumberState(false);
                                  await handlePhoneNumberChange();
                                }}
                              />
                            )}
                          </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                  <div/>
                  <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
                    {/** Email Verification */}
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                      <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                        <label
                          for="first-name"
                          class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                        >
                          Email
                        </label>
                        <Buttons
                          title="Send Email"
                          onClick={sendOtp}
                          outline
                          class="   inline-flex 
                                justify-center 
                                py-2 px-4 border 
                                border-transparent 
                                shadow-sm text-sm 
                                font-medium rounded-md 
                                text-white bg-red-400 
                                hover:bg-red-400 
                                focus:outline-none f
                                ocus:ring-2 
                                focus:ring-offset-2 
                                focus:ring-red-500"
                        />
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                        <label
                          for="last-name"
                          class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                        >
                          Verification Code
                        </label>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="last-name"
                          id="last-name"
                          autocomplete="family-name"
                          class="mt-1 
                                      focus:ring-red-400 
                                      focus:border-red-400 
                                      block w-full 
                                      shadow-sm sm:text-sm 
                                      border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {/** End Email Verification */}
                    {/** Phone Number change */}
                      <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                      <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                        <label
                          for="first-name"
                          class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                        >
                          New Mobile Number
                        </label>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="first-name"
                          id="first-name"
                          autocomplete="given-name"
                          class="mt-1 
                                      focus:ring-red-400 
                                      focus:border-red-400 
                                      block w-full 
                                      shadow-sm sm:text-sm 
                                      border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {/** End Email change */}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/*     ------------   Mobile Number Change  ----------------    */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Security;
```

**Above mention between two section, the password field should be added**

Comment: In React, you should use components: In your case, create a new component where you can handle your whole form (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html). If what you want is to keep the logic separate just for your password field, then you can create a component just for that, although unnecessary IMO. Just avoid DOM manipulation the way you are trying to do. 
You should read more about React elements and how React actually works behind the scenes: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: I just need to import this password field because In my project I have many forms, But the problem is I want to import whole this component (including all the div tags as well) because of it is in tailwind css.

Comment: I have edited the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lets assume this is your form:

```
import PasswordField from "/PasswordField"

const Form = () => {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("")
  const submitForm = () => {
    //your logic for submitting form
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
      <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <input type="text" value={lastName} onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)} />
      <PasswordField password={password} setPassword={setPassword} />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Note we are importing the PasswordField component to be used inside the form, and passing the value and the function to change that value as props to the PasswordField component.

Now lets create the Password component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const PasswordField = (props) => {
   return (
    <div>
      <label class="font-medium block mb-1 mt-6 text-gray-700" for="password">
        Password
      </label>
      <input id={"password"} type="password" value={props.password} onChange={(e) => props.setPassword(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default PasswordField;
```

Obviously, you need to add your classes and styling accordingly, but I thing this could get you going.

Comment: dear sir because of repeating the same code again and again I want to take these files to a separate file. But the problem with this code

Comment: Which is mentioned as "Password Field",  In this above field I need to pass all the div classes as well otherwise password field is not working. That is my problem. I want to pass div (  <div class="relative w-full">) and the  elements inside that div.

Comment: Well, then add the divs and classes you need. My answer is a very simple example that you can take as a reference for learning how to work with components. I suggest you keep reading more about React